# .NET on Azure reads Invalid Connection String

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb, azure, connection-string

I'm trying to connect to a mongodb database in my ASP.NET MVC application.  The connection works on localhost but not on my Azure hosted website.  There I get the error:

```
Invalid connection string 'Data Source=tcp:ta7dgzuq.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=sixty-vocab;User ID=user@server;Password=xxxxxx'.
```

The error message is pretty correct - that connection string is invalid, because it's not the one I should be using to connect to the database.  I have this connection string in the web config:

```
<add name="MongoDB" connectionString="mongodb://sixty-vocab.connectai.com:2701/user" />
```

I'm reading the connection string like this:

```
string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MongoDB"].ConnectionString;
```

How can I get Azure to read the correct string?

Comment: Maybe it's a web.config transformation problem. Take a look when you publish, which Configuration will be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure seems to store its own connection strings separate from the web.config.  I went to the Configure tab of Windows Azure and added a new connection string.
[image: Azure connection strings]

I also made a pretty dumb mistake and initially entered "mongo-db" instead of "MongoDB" for the connection string name.  Now that I entered the connection string as seen above (matching connection string in web.config) I can connect to the mongo database.  It works!